# Multi-Page Form Not Loading to Top of Screen

Tags: javascript, forms, reload, multipage

I have created a multi-page registration form for a website.  Due to the page length differences when a user clicks through each page they wind up proportionally in the same page between the steps.  This can leave the user having to scroll up to see the form steps.  I hope that made sense, but my main question is how do I change the script so that it will reload to the top of the page at every interval?

Here is the current bit of code for the next page navigation:

```
<button style='float:right;' class='next-tab mover' type='submit' rel='\" + next + \"'>Next</button>\
```

This was taken from a php script.  I have tried some obvious tests like using #top, but I could not get it to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added width and height to the first div helped out.  i also made the second div absolute to the first div:

```
<form id="form1" >
<div id="divHeader"     style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:20px;width:800px;height:600px;" >
Form Steps: <br />
<ul>
<li>Step1:  ....</li>
<li>Step2:  ....</li>
<li>Step3:  ....</li>
<li>Step4:  ....</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="divUserInput" style="width:100%;position:absolute;left:20px;top:140px;" >
<!--Form content here....-->
<table border="0">
<tr><td>Question 1</td><td><input type="text" id="txtQ1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Question 2</td><td><input type="text" id="txtQ2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Question 3</td><td><input type="text" id="txtQ3" /></td></tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, I tried it out and it worked, except one problem.  The form loses its place on the page.  The elements below it in the layout are pushed up behind the form.  `<div style="position: absolute; top">` this is my div call, is there a quick fix for it to keep the space?

Comment: hmm in your div you may need to add how many pixels from the top you want the div to be positioned from:    <div style="position: aboslute; top: 10px">  you may want to put the rest of the content in another div below the first div with position: relitive to the top div.  If you could post your html i may be able to have more ideas.  thanks.

Comment: I tried but it did not work.  The code has many layer to it, is there a specific piece I should display to give an idea?

Comment: I'll mock something up and post.  see if that may help.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared it up a bit for me and I was able to make it work.